# Java, запись в файл со смещением

Tags: java, файлы

1. Вопрос, как в Java(каким классом?) можно производить запись в середину файла(перезаписать блок по смещению).
2. Каким образом создать файл определенной длинны заполненный мусором/нулями(так называемый Instant File Initialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Вопрос, как в Java(каким классом?) можно производить запись в середину
>   файла(перезаписать блок по смещению).

```
try (RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("test.dat", "rw")) {
    f.seek(somePositionInBytes);
    f.write(someData);
}
```

> Каким образом создать файл определенной длинны заполненный
>   мусором/нулями(так называемый Instant File Initialization).

```
try (RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("test.dat", "rw")) {
    f.setLength(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```